# Selection in aggregated view scenario in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I’m trying to select elements in a multi-model scenario using the getAggregateSelection(selection) function. This function used to work fine earlier but has started resulting in the following error:

```
"viewer3D.min.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') at viewer3D.min.js:18:1301021 at u.setSelection (viewer3D.min.js:18:1301094) at c.setAggregateSelection (viewer3D.min.js:18:1305012) at C.de.setAggregateSelection (viewer3D.min.js:18:638482) at <anonymous>:1:15"
```

The getAggregateSelction function is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried the `setAggregateSelection` in one of my samples, and it seems to be working fine. Are you sure you're using the correct format for the input parameter? It should be:

```js
viewer.setAggregateSelection([
  {
    model: someModelInstance,
    ids: [123, 456]
  },
  {
    model: anotherModelInstance,
    ids: [789]
  }
]);
```

[image]